# Assigning ng-model attributes from a parent controller object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have related object listed using ng-repeat which should generate a form for a separate nested angular controller. I'm trying to set ng-model attributes using a parent controller's object.

For now the controller looks like:

```
wha.controller('ConnectionRequestsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.new_connection_request = {};

  $scope.create = function () {
    console.log($scope.new_connection_request);
  };
});
```

Console.log prints {} literal. If I remove the definition for new_connection_request from my controller, I get undefined.

I'm trying assign the new_connection_request objects values to a form that it nested inside a related object called contact_suggestion.

```
//nested inside contact suggestion controller with contact_suggestion object

<form ng-controller="ConnectionRequestsCtrl" ng-submit="create()">
  <input ng-model="new_connection_request.sender_id" ng-value="contact_suggestion.user_id" type="hidden"></input>
  <input ng-model="new_connection_request.recipient_id" ng-value="contact_suggestion.connection_id" type="hidden"></input>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Connect</button>
</form>
```

The form values are correctly set in the generated html.

```
<form ng-controller="ConnectionRequestsCtrl" ng-submit="create()" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <input ng-model="new_connection_request.sender_id" ng-value="contact_suggestion.user_id" type="hidden" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" value="157">
  <input ng-model="new_connection_request.recipient_id" ng-value="contact_suggestion.connection_id" type="hidden" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" value="2154">
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Connect</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try setting the parent object's values in the `ConnectionRequestsCtrl` itself? The `$scope` object should prototypically inherit from the `ContactSuggestionController` and hence be able to refer `contact_suggestion` object from there. If you want to set it in view, you can use ng-init. However, setting defaults in controller is recommended.

Comment: I can do something like 'ng-submit' => 'create(contact_suggestion)', 
 $scope.create = function () { var connection_request = {
      recipient_id: contact_suggestion.connection_id
    } } . Is this the recommended way to build the object in angular? I shouldn't bind the values to a form?